# Color of flag icon changes back to dark red after page reload

Tags: bug, comments, design, comment-flags

This is a very trivial bug but I am a pretty liberal comment flagger so this will probably bother me a lot (which trivial things like this usually do).

I noticed that the color of the flag icon next to flagged comments was changed to a pink color which I think is great since it's less in-your-face and distinguishes from the hover state of the flag icon. But I noticed it is only pink right after you flag the comment. When you reload the page, the color changes back to the dark red color which is the same as the hover state color.

[image: comments with flags before and after page reload]

In this screenshot, the bottom two comments were flagged before reloading the page. While the first comment was flagged after page reload and no further reloads.

Comment: Providing a comment so folks can test this. Please do be sure to retract once you're finished, though.

Comment: @Spevacus may I too? :P

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I don't remember inviting you ;) - But I *suppose*...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Only so long as it's a custom flag. (Those no longer result in the comment being deleted immediately.)

Comment: I think I figured out the cause of the issue. Judging by that, I don't think the red color after the reload is buggy, but that the pink color is. Basically, there's a CSS style that sets the flag button to 40% opacity by default, which is what causes the light gray color. Upon submitting the flag, the style is not removed. However, on the next page load it's served without that style (100% opacity).

Comment: Posting a comment will also change the color.